# Как использовать LINQ для заполнения List

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте!
Подскажите пожалуйста, как переписать функцию `GetValues()` с помощью LINQ.
И если дадите дельную ссылку на изучение LINQ(кроме MSDN), буду благодарен.

Вот код:

```
enum MyEnum { FIRST, SECOND };
class MyClass
{
    List<MyObject> MyList = new List<MyObject>();

    //constructor
    internal MyClass()
    {
        MyList.Add(new MyObject(MyEnum.FIRST, 1));
        MyList.Add(new MyObject(MyEnum.FIRST, 2));
        MyList.Add(new MyObject(MyEnum.FIRST, 3));
        MyList.Add(new MyObject(MyEnum.SECOND, 1));


        List<int> collectedValues = GetValues(MyList, MyEnum.SECOND);
    }

    List<int> GetValues(List<MyObject> MyList, MyEnum ExceptionEnum)
    {
        List<int> returnList = new List<int>();
        for(int i = 0; i < MyList.Count; i++)
        {
            if(MyList[i].MyName == ExceptionEnum)
                continue;
            returnList.Add(MyList[i].Value);
        }
        return returnList;
    }
}

class MyObject
{
    internal MyEnum MyName;
    internal int Value; 

    public MyObject(MyEnum MyName, int Value)
    {
        this.MyName = MyName;
        this.Value = Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Вряд ли найдется что-то лучше чем MSDN

Comment: [Литература по C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/416585/184217).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Что-то вроде:

```
List<int> GetValues(List<MyObject> MyList, MyEnum ExceptionEnum)
{
    return MyList.Where(i => i.MyName != ExceptionEnum).Select(i => i.Value).ToList();
}
```

Ваш код:

```
if(MyList[i].MyName == ExceptionEnum)
    continue;
returnList.Add(MyList[i].Value);
```

Будет равен:

```
if(MyList[i].MyName != ExceptionEnum)
    returnList.Add(MyList[i].Value);
```

И отсюда следует, что нам надо взять все элементы из `MyList`, где `MyListItem.MyName != ExceptionEnum`. Тут нам приходит на помощь `Where-clause`. Далее проходим и вытягиваем `Value` из каждого элемента с помощью `Select-clause`. И в конце просто конвертим `IEnumerable` в `List` с помощью `ToList()`.

Насчет изучения LINQ, то посоветую сайт [товарища Метанита](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/15.1.php).

Comment: Where в данном случае недостаточно. Посмотри какие значения он складывает в список, который возвращает

Comment: @Grundy невнимательность - моя беда. Спасибо, подправил

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш ответ